# Numpy where conditional statement along axis 0

Tags: python, numpy, vector, conditional-statements

I have a 1D vector `Zc` containing n elements that are 2D arrays.  I want to find the index of each 2D array that equals `np.ones(Zc[i].shape)`.

```
a = np.zeros((5,5))
b = np.ones((5,5))*4
c = np.ones((5,5))
d = np.ones((5,5))*2

Zc = np.stack((a,b,c,d))

for i in range(len(Zc)):
    a = np.ones(Zc[i].shape)
    b = Zc[i]
    if np.array_equal(a,b):
        print(i)
    else:
        pass
```

Which returns `2`.  The code above works and returns the correct answer, but I want to know if there a vectorized way to achieve the same result?

Comment: So every Zc[i] has a different shape in general?

Comment: Look at `(Zc==a[None,...]).all(axis=(1,2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of hpaulj's comment:

```
>>> allones = (Zc == np.array(np.ones(Zc[i].shape))).all(axis=(1,2))
>>> np.where(allones)[0][0]
2
```